# How to pivot temperature per month in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, average

I can make an average of the temperatures per year this way:

```
select Ville, 
       AVG(Temperature) as Temperature 
from Meteo 
where DateDonnees between '2011-01-01' and '2012-01-01' 
group by  Ville
```

[image]

The problem is that I would like to have the temperature per month.

So I found a [post](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/01/sql-pivot-converting-rows-to-columns.html) that explains how to do that:

```
select * from(
select Ville, Temperature as Temperature from Meteo where DateDonnees between '2011-01-01' and '2012-01-01' group by  Ville
)
pivot(
cast(AVG(Temperature)) AS DECIMAL(4, 1) for DateDonnees in (
    1 JAN, 2 FEB, 3 MAR, 4 APR, 5 MAY, 6 JUN,
    7 JUL, 8 AUG, 9 SEP, 10 OCT, 11 NOV, 12 DEC)
))
```

and it throws `"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'pivot'."` error.

This is the result I would like to see:

[image]

Comment: Please show us the result that you want, as tabular text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MONTH` function could be placed in a lateral join and then used in CASE logic to pivot the months.  Something like this

```
select Ville as City, 
       avg(case when mo.mon=1 then Temperature else 0 end) Jan,
       avg(case when mo.mon=2 then Temperature else 0 end) Feb,
       avg(case when mo.mon=3 then Temperature else 0 end) Mar,
       avg(case when mo.mon=4 then Temperature else 0 end) Apr,
       avg(case when mo.mon=5 then Temperature else 0 end) May,
       avg(case when mo.mon=6 then Temperature else 0 end) Jun,
       avg(case when mo.mon=7 then Temperature else 0 end) Jul,
       avg(case when mo.mon=8 then Temperature else 0 end) Aug,
       avg(case when mo.mon=9 then Temperature else 0 end) Sep,
       avg(case when mo.mon=10 then Temperature else 0 end) Oct,
       avg(case when mo.mon=11 then Temperature else 0 end) Nov,
       avg(case when mo.mon=12 then Temperature else 0 end) [Dec]
from Meteo m
     cross apply
     (select month(m.DateDonnees) mon) mo
where DateDonnees between '2011-01-01' and '2012-01-01' 
group by Ville;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend conditional aggregation:

```
select city,
    avg(case when datedonnees >= '20200101' and datedonnees < '20200201' then temperature end) jan,
    avg(case when datedonnees >= '20200201' and datedonnees < '20200301' then temperature end) feb,
    avg(case when datedonnees >= '20201201' and datedonnees < '20200401' then temperature end) mar,
    ...
    avg(case when datedonnees >= '20201201' and datedonnees < '20210101' then temperature end) dec
from meteo
where datedonnees >= '20200101' and datedonnees < '20210101'
group by city
```

We can shorten the syntax a little with `month()`, but it might be less efficient than half-open intervals:

```
select city,
    avg(case when month(datedonnees) =  1 then temperature end) jan,
    avg(case when month(datedonnees) =  2 then temperature end) feb,
    avg(case when month(datedonnees) =  3 then temperature end) mar,
    ...
    avg(case when month(datedonnees) = 12 then temperature end) dec
from meteo
where datedonnees >= '20200101' and datedonnees < '20210101'
group by city
```